# Passing parameters to a CGI program using the URL (python)

Tags: python, html, cgi

As the title suggests, I'm trying to pass parameters into my cgi script so that when you type in (for example): www.helloworld.com/cgi-bin/world.py?post=101, the script will display that post

I've tried the following:

```
link = '<a href="world.py?post=%s">test</a>' % postNumber

link = cgi.FieldStorage()
id = link.getvalue('post')
print id
```

but the value of id is nothing. It's like it's not reading the link properly or something.

Please help!

Comment: "Nothing"?  Please print what you **are** getting and **update** the question with the response your CGI script is getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
id = link["post"].value
print id
```